# setText for Textviews and read HTML tags

Tags: android, html, textbox

I have a String , this string may contain any value(i mean it may include HTML tags).
i created a TextView in java and now i  need to set this text to textview.
Generally

```
String str;
Textview tv = new TextView(this);

tv.setText(str);
```

but if the str = &lt b &rt   **this is testing**      &lt /b &rt 
then in this case i have to set the text for the textview with Bold (need to read HTML tags and assign according to that).

are there any API's available in java to read HTML and how can i proceed on this..

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this.

```
String htmlStr = "&lt b &rt this is testing &lt /b &rt";
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlStr));
```

> Method Html.fromHtml(String) -
>
> Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any  tags in the HTML will display as a generic replacement image which your program can then go through and replace with real images.
>   This uses TagSoup to handle real HTML, including all of the brokenness found in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String myHtml = "&lt b &rt  <b> this is testing </b>     &lt /b &rt";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtml));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your html content to strings.xml and refer it form there. If you have large html content you can put the content in strings.xml between ![CDATA[ and  ]].

In your strings.xml add

```
<string name="myhtml><![CDATA[<html>  your html conten </html> ]]> </string>
```

In your activity

```
Textview tv= new TextView(this);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.myhtml));
```